# Подсчет количества слов в тексте

Tags: python, re, count

На данном сайте есть [задание](https://www.codewars.com/kata/56b3b27cadd4ad275500000c/train/python): посчитать количество слов.
Словами считаются непрерывные последовательности английских алфавитных символов (от А до z)
Вот примеры:

```
Hello there, little user5453 374 ())$. I’d been using my sphere as a stool. Slow-moving target 839342 was hit by OMGd-63 or K4mp. 
contains "words" 
['Hello', 'there', 'little', 'user', 'I', 'd', 'been', 'using', 'my','sphere', 'as', 'a', 'stool', 'Slow', 'moving', 'target', 'was', 'hit', 'by', 'OMGd', 'or', 'K', 'mp']
```

Некоторые из слов следует исключить. Вот эти слова:

```
"a", "the", "on", "at", "of", "upon", "in" and "as", case-insensitive.
```

Моё решение такое:
Разбиваем по словам - убираем всё лишнее. В цикле проверяем, не запрещённое ли слово или пустая строка и увеличиваем счетчик

```
import codewars_test as test
import re

except_word = ["a", "the", "on", "at", "of", "upon", "in", "as"]


def word_count(s):
    all_word = re.sub(r'([^A-Za-z]+)', r' ', s).split(' ')
    print(all_word)
    cnt = 0
    for word in all_word:
        if word in except_word or word == '':
            continue
        else:
            cnt += 1
    return cnt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test.assert_equals(word_count("hello there"), 2)
    test.assert_equals(word_count("hello there and a hi"), 4)
    test.assert_equals(word_count("I'd like to say goodbye"), 6)
    test.assert_equals(word_count("Slow-moving user6463 has been here"), 6)
    test.assert_equals(word_count("%^&abc!@# wer45tre"), 3)
    test.assert_equals(word_count("abc123abc123abc"), 3)
    test.assert_equals(word_count("Really2374239847 long ^&#$&(*@# sequence"), 3)

    long_text = r"""
            I’d been using my sphere as a stool. I traced counterclockwise circles on it with my fingertips and it shrank until I could palm it. My bolt had shifted while I’d been sitting. I pulled it up and yanked the pleats straight as I careered around tables, chairs, globes, and slow-moving fraas. I passed under a stone arch into the Scriptorium. The place smelled richly of ink. Maybe it was because an ancient fraa and his two fids were copying out books there. But I wondered how long it would take to stop smelling that way if no one ever used it at all; a lot of ink had been spent there, and the wet smell of it must be deep into everything.
            """

    test.assert_equals(word_count(long_text), 112)
```

Базовые тесты:

```
        test.assert_equals(word_count("hello there"), 2)
        test.assert_equals(word_count("hello there and a hi"), 4)
        test.assert_equals(word_count("I'd like to say goodbye"), 6)
        test.assert_equals(word_count("Slow-moving user6463 has been here"), 6)
        test.assert_equals(word_count("%^&abc!@# wer45tre"), 3)
        test.assert_equals(word_count("abc123abc123abc"), 3)
        test.assert_equals(word_count("Really2374239847 long ^&#$&(*@# sequence"), 3)
```

Функция проходит все базовые тесты, не выдаёт правильный ответ на длинном тексте
вот пример базовый:

```
Example Input 2

I’d been using my sphere as a stool. I traced counterclockwise circles on it with my fingertips and it shrank until I could palm it. My bolt had shifted while I’d been sitting. I pulled it up and yanked the pleats straight as I careered around tables, chairs, globes, and slow-moving fraas. I passed under a stone arch into the Scriptorium. The place smelled richly of ink. Maybe it was because an ancient fraa and his two fids were copying out books there. But I wondered how long it would take to stop smelling that way if no one ever used it at all; a lot of ink had been spent there, and the wet smell of it must be deep into everything.

Example Output 2

112
```

Моя функция выдаёт 113
Может, неправильно понимаю задание (перевод с Google)? В случайных тестах на сервере моё решение всегда от 1 до 3 лишних слов выдаёт.

Объясните, пожалуйста, в чём причина? Как будто что-то (а что, не пойму) забываю удалить.

Comment: Кстати, пустую строку ``""`` можно точно также внести в список, а еще лучше в множество, и не проверять отдельно ``word == ''``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В задании написано: **case-insensitive**.

А ведь слово может начинаться и с большой буквы, и, например, "and" и "And" — разные слова.

Comment: Вы совершенно правы - в тексте есть The и его нужно тоже удалять case-insensitive(без учета регистра) - буду исправлять.СПАСИБО!!!!!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/282277/Эникейщик Рано порадовался! Рандомная проверка показывает что одно слово всё равно лишнее - только одно во всех тестах

Comment: значит, неправильно исправил :)

Comment: "~!a5^9 $"_Wf >>B'Cu2y`l y;ul(o&z $}!4. '5g4mo:D J~{>X/5 8@]UuP)~i 4EIbl$ L?~pNR (7Q425$"z# D[mUBy&pK r|pMgF,Y+ MkRWj 7siez-Zg CND%7s+ t3M]d8-D~ )K|ePlH }Ia?z^] ol8g- v!KCBv\srg hFle.cm|a| (N3o`7^VOG )/Fx, <=h{2m -q(k$l4 vcPRO a[Ouu'd^Pg 9&@bvE& ;xCM!5o pR_;b<]} e~4:}H 1f.ZXoo( a0=`C;v ()@Lp&IJIV .{UGR8e #dQQ2A! jrXUM ^>)-Q: r].AW 05:vZ6 Q?ZG:ygp }Nq~|l+"- T:?Ght tubm-Bo A:F0c]bW ,>1,IexH [3.X" jHT.}s/\:c :+Ug\jdV ypga!Q1(% d'Dn@UJ3Sz hE^IN1 MAo-ysP Y&#ru1A a~eP#: ],g)\0J; G<.DbMD9a ([WK[?%8!  ВОТ тестовая строка должно быть 117 у меня 118 НЕ ПОЙМУ!

Comment: Задайте новый вопрос с новым кодом. Потому что без кода это будет просто гадание.